# stat in bash returns differently in Mac and Windows

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I tried to use stat command in bash on my Mac and Windows. The first pic is what i got in Windows and second one in Mac. Why are they different? Can I change it to Windows version since it's more readable. Thanks.[image]

[image]

Comment: GNU stat and BSD stat are different programs, you need to install GNU coreutils to get GNU stat (i.e the one you have on Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS, add the `-x` option to `stat`.

```
touch samplefile
stat -x samplefile
  File: "samplefile"
  Size: 0            FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0644/-rw-r--r--)         Uid: (  501/     jrf)  Gid: (   20/   staff)
Device: 1,3   Inode: 28652313    Links: 1
Access: Sat Jan 16 08:33:43 2021
Modify: Sat Jan 16 08:33:43 2021
Change: Sat Jan 16 08:33:43 2021
```